# Simplifying a Complex Number

Tags: complex-numbers

I have $\left ( \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}}{1+i}\right )^{2014}$. I wish to simplify this to standard form.

I simplify to $\left ( e^{i\frac{\pi}{12}} \right )^{2014}$ I can evaluate and simplify $e^{i\frac{\pi}{12}}$, but how do I handle the power of $2014$?

Comment: Your simplification can't be correct. The first number has absolute value $\left|\dfrac{1}{1+i}\right|^{2014}$, the second one has absolute value equal to $1$.

Comment: The new way to display up votes on comments looks horrible. **Edit:** I realise now it's due to the exponent: Still, the vote count should be aligned with the first character in the comment.

Comment: You're missing a factor of $ 1/ \sqrt{2}$ from mulitplying both numerator and denominator of $(1+i)^{-1}$ by it's conjugate. In any case,, maybe de Moivre's theorem would help.

Answer (score 2):

The simplification should be as follows:

$$\left ( \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}}{1+i}\right )^{2014}
=\left ( \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}}{\sqrt 2e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}\right )^{2014}
=\left ( \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{12}}}{\sqrt 2}\right )^{2014}$$

Then just follow the rules for raising a power to a power.

Comment: That was the part I was stuck on though. How do I know what $e^{ i \frac{2014\pi}{12}}$ is?

Comment: You should be familiar with Euler's Formula: $e^{ix}=\cos x + i \sin x$ which is periodic.  So then $e^{ix} = e^{i(x\pm 2n\pi)}$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$.  So then, $e^{ i \frac{2014\pi}{12}} = e^{ i(166\pi+ \frac{22\pi}{12})} = e^{ i \frac{22\pi}{12}}= e^{ i \frac{11\pi}{6}} =  e^{- i \frac{\pi}{6}} $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For integers $n$, $$(e^{i\theta})^n = e^{i(n\theta)}.$$